# Can a .NET stack trace be generated that excludes internal methods?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

Sometimes when an exception happens on a .NET class method, that method itself internally is calling a bunch of other methods but the error happens inside one of those. This makes for a bloated and messy stack trace with more "meaningless" stuff than needed. Is there a way to get a stack trace that stops at the public .NET method that caused the error vs having it show all the internals of the .NET methods?

An example of this would be ADO.NET's ExecuteNonQuery(). Internally that calls like 5-6 functions and the exception may not happen until that 6th nested function and so the stack trace shows all of those internals which we can't do anything about or care about. It would be nice and cleaner if it stopped at ExecuteNonQuery() since that's the public facing .NET method.

Comment: Are there any practical reasons? You can catch and re-throw, but why?

Comment: Are you sure the internal method names are pointless? E.g. if `ExecuteNonQuery` throws a `NullReferenceException`, where do you start looking? Versus if the internal method names include the word `Parameter`, does that not help you more quickly zoom in on where you should be looking?

Comment: You could create a custom exception class & filter out the things YOU don't want in the stack trace.

Comment: When I was a boy, we didn't have stack traces of useful symbol names, merely a collection of hex addresses.   Rejoice and embrace the verbose nature of .NET exceptions

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question.  It seems like a reasonable thing to ask -- in fact most places I've worked have had somethings similar in places to highlight where in _our_ code errors occur.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright I suspect part of the downvotes (not from me) are related to the fact that the OP has ignored the multiple questions asked of him/her. That would be interpreted by some members here as immature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no", you can't change the way .NET generates stack traces.  When a stack trace is generated, it shows every call site.  However, if you want to have some custom behaviors, you can write some custom code to edit the output of a stack trace you generate.

To generate a stack trace, you use code like this:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           
StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
```

The constructor will generate the stacktrace data, and `.GetFrames()` will return the methods to you.  From that point, you can filter them as you wish (use `stackFrame.GetMethod()` to get the method info for each frame -- either to filter it or to add it to a `StringBuilder` for your string output, etc)

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx